# FlowDocument has too much white space on lines

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument, flowdocumentreader

Following `btnTest_Click(...)` event in my `WPF .NET5` app successfully displays the content of a `RichTextBox` into a `FlowDocumentReader`. But, as shown in the images below, the different page viewing modes of the `FlowDocumentReader` create excessive amounts of whitespace on lines. **Question**: Why it is happening, what I may be missing here, and how can we resolve the issue?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_RTBFlowDocTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_RTBFlowDocTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DockPanel Name="mainPanel">
            <ToolBar Name="mainToolBar" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Click="btnTest_Click"/>
            </ToolBar>
            <RichTextBox Name="rtbTest" AcceptsTab="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
            <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="fdReader" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsScrollViewEnabled="True">
                <FlowDocument IsOptimalParagraphEnabled="True" IsHyphenationEnabled="True" TextAlignment="Left"></FlowDocument>
            </FlowDocumentReader>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var range = new TextRange(rtbTest.Document.ContentStart, rtbTest.Document.ContentEnd);
    if (!range.IsEmpty)
    {
        if(fdReader.Document.Blocks.Count > 0)
            fdReader.Document.Blocks.Clear();

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            range.Save(stream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
            var copyto = new TextRange(fdReader.Document.ContentEnd, fdReader.Document.ContentEnd);
            copyto.Load(stream, DataFormats.XamlPackage);
        }
    }
    rtbTest.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    fdReader.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

**Original display of the app before clicking the `Test` button**:

[image]

**Single pageview display after the above code ran**:

[image]

**Single Scroll pageview display after above code ran**:

[image]

**Multiple pageview display after the above code ran**:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the document content affects the document presentation. It’s difficult to understand what causes the problem without [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you leave only 2-3 paragraphs around the _**"break"**_ sentence, save the document to `*.rtf` file and include the file to the post (in text format)?

Comment: @Jackdaw Your above comment resolved the issue. The document content indeed affects the document presentation. I had copied the original content from [this file](https://ufile.io/c3yw5x2x) that had too many spaces. After reading your comment, I deleted those spaces to create a new file [uploaded here](https://ufile.io/ldezcziu). Now the app displays the content properly in all three pageview modes. You may want to explain a reason for the issue in a `response` - and I'll mark that as an `Answer`. Note: The two uploaded files will be deleted automatically after 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly as expected: your source text file is including lots of `NewLine` characters for line feed inside the sentences and spaces used for lines content alignment:

[image]

In a flow document, the content adapts itself to fit the container, but `NewLine` characters inside sentences prevented the `FlowDocument` control to format the text correctly.

Therefore, it's necessary to make some source text processing before loading it to the `FlowDocument` control.